# GWT DisclosurePanel remove vertical line

Tags: gwt

I tried to override a few css properties of the gwt-DisclosurePanel and gwt-DisclosurePanel-open rules to try and remove the vertical line but failed to do so. Here is the image:

[image]

How do I remove this vertical line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border line in the `DisclosurePanel` content comes from this rule (in Clean theme as an example):

```
.gwt-DisclosurePanel .content {
  border-left: 3px solid #e7e7e7; // Here is your border
  padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

Always use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox or Chrome's built in [Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) to debug issues like that. You would get the required CSS rule to override in just a few seconds.

Comment: Thank You @Strelok. That fixed my problem. I also learned something about css today.